# ScreenToWorldPoint возвращает координаты камеры при параметре Input.mousePosition

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-faq

Изучаю Unity и не могу разобраться с ScreenToWorldPoint:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Debug.Log(GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
}
```

Вроде как написано всё правильно и координаты должно переводить, но куда не нажми - выдаёт координаты самой камеры. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask код не картинкой пжлста :)

Answer (score 7):

Идем в [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно нас интересует приписка к первой перегрузке метода:

> plus a z position for depth (for example, a camera clipping plane)

---

Камера - это, вообще говоря, довольно запутанная штука для неподготовленного человека:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Зачастую**, экран - это и есть `near clipping plane`, в любом случае "экран" - это секущая фрустум камеры плоскость, куда мышь и кликает в данном случае.

Проблема в том, что точки на этой плоскости имеют 3 координаты:

1. x - ось x
2. y - ось y
3. z - расстояние от камеры до плоскости

А мышь, чисто логически, имеет 2 координаты - x и y, про какой-то z она ничего не знает. `Input.mousePosition` вообще возвращает `Vector3`, с 0 вместо координаты z. И на самом деле это валидная ситуация: плоскость на расстоянии 0 от камеры - это плоскость с как бы "нулевой" площадью, т.е. любая точка на этой плоскости будет спроецирована в 3д пространство с такими координатами:

- `x => cameraX + 0`, 0, т.к. у нас "пустая" плоскость, никуда там не
  деться
- `y => cameraY + 0`, 0, т.к. смотри x
- `z => cameraZ + 0`, 0,
  т.к. мы передали нулевое расстояние от плоскости до камеры

В итоге получаем преобразование:

```
input: Vector3(x, y, 0)
output: Vector3(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ)
```

Как видно, координаты изначальной точки вообще никак не влияют на преобразованные координаты, а все дело кроется именно в z = 0 во входных данных.

Решение?

Использовать плоскость экрана, которая удалена от камеры на расстояние, прописанное в камере:

```
var screenToCameraDistance = camera.nearClipPlane;
```

---

**TL;DR**

```
var camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
var mousePos2D = Input.mousePosition;
var screenToCameraDistance = camera.nearClipPlane;

var mousePosNearClipPlane = new Vector3(mousePos2D.x, mousePos2D.y, screenToCameraDistance)

// искомая точка в мировых координатах
var worldPointPos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosNearClipPlane);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Доступно и хорошо объяснил! Побольше бы таких людей тут)

Comment: @Jokily так вы тогда авторов ответов награждайте +1 и принятым ответом, иначе желания помогать с каждым разом все меньше ;)